# Как создать интерактивную диаграмму типа "Солнечые лучи" в таблице Excel с помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, openpyxl

Диаграмма необходима интерактивная (конечный пользователь таблицы мог в Excel'e ручками своими редактировать диаграмму как его душе угодно), не просто сгенерированная картинка.

openpyxl позволяет рисовать такие графики, но, увы, не имеет в своем арсенале методов для создания именно "солнечных лучей".

Какие варианты есть и существуют ли они вообще, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Какая OS используется?

Comment: @АлексейР windows 10

Comment: Тогда можно использовать "родную" объектную модель Excel через win32com - что-то вроде https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761528/python-excel-and-charts-using-win32com

Comment: Нужный вам тип диаграммы - `XlChartType.xlSunburst` (значение 120)

Comment: @АлексейР спасибо за рекомендацию, попробую!